# How to figure out which exact python app regularly results in crashes of Python.app?

Tags: macos, crash, python

I have several python (server) apps running on my Macbook.
One of them regularly crashes on my system, resulting in a desktop notification popup with the message: `Python quit unexpectedly`.

Checking the crash logs on my system in `/Users/jottr/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` I find several reports pertaining to Python.

```
$ head -n 8 Python_2015-12-12-201816_hostname.crash

Process:               Python [605]
Path:                  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               2.7.10 (2.7.10)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Python [605]
User ID:               501
```

These crash logs are too unspecific to establish which exact process keeps crashing.

**How can I debug which exact python process/app crashes the interpreter?**

Comment: Possibly not a solution, but worth a try: Write a small bash script to use `ps -e | grep python >> /path/to/some/file` and have it started with launchd. Once a crash occurs, you can cross-reference the PID and see which parameters had been used (effectively seeing which script was running with that process).

Comment: thx @Phoenix.  Probably worth a try. Still hoping for a more straight forward solution though.